# VB6 compiled DLL giving CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE issue

Tags: dll, dependencies, vb6

I have compiled a DLL yesterday in VB6 and it gives me CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE issue.
However the same DLL compiled in 2023 does not give this error.
There has been no code change nor any change in the process or system where and how the DLL is being built.

Tried comparing DLL, Checking dependencies using dependency walker tool, does not help
How to get rid of CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE  error?

Comment: Have you registered the DLL? Why have you tagged the question .NET, which VB6 isn't? Where do you get CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE and what is the code that causes it?

Comment: How could you compile the .NET code in VB6? This is a different technology. Please rephraze your question.

Comment: Not compiling .NET code in VB6. The DLL is build from Visual basic project which is ran in Microsoft visual basic 6.0

Comment: There is not enough information. Please explain how the error is being generated and show the code that does so.  Also gserg's point about registering the DLL is very important.